# Example of Möbius map with certain properties

Tags: complex-analysis

Give an example of Möbius transform which maps unit circle to real axis.

Let $G=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ and $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: \Im z=0\}$.

Let's construct the map $T(z)$ such that $T$ maps $1,i,-1$ to $1,0,\infty$, respectively.

Then $T(z)=(z,1,i,-1)=\dfrac{z-i}{z+1}:\left( \dfrac{1-i}{1+1}\right)=\dfrac{2(z-i)}{(z+1)(1-i)}$.

Since Möbius map is defined uniquely by 3 points and also it maps circles in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ to circles in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ hence it follows that $T$ indeed maps $G$ onto $D$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Would be grateful for checking!

Comment: Isn't  $G=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$?

Comment: @ThomasShelby, ohh yes! Sorry for this!

Comment: @ThomasShelby, edited.

Comment: @ThomasShelby, yes. You can take a look at Conway's book.

Comment: Yes,your solution looks okay to me.

Comment: All you need to do is verity that $T$ is a Möbius transformation and $T(1) = 1, T(i) = 0, T(-1) = \infty$. Then Propositions 3.8, 3.14 (or indeed, 3.10) shows that $T$ maps the circle into the real axis "circle".

Comment: You have the correct answer, but I don't understand the $:$ notation you have used above. I just worked it out letting $T(z) = {az+b \over cz+d}$ and solving for values (there is one unimportant ambiguity).

Comment: @copper.hat, honestly to say i did not understand your last comment. Could you clarify it please?

Comment: To find $T$ I just let $T$ be as above and solve for $a,b,c,d $ (or $b,d, {a \over c}$ in this case) using the constraints $T(1)=1, T(i)=0,T(-1)=\infty$. This gives $b=-ai$, $c=d$ and ${a \over c} = {2 \over 1-i}$ which is what you have above.